# Выравнивание двух блоков относительно друг друга CSS

Tags: html, css

Возникла проблема, хочу выровнять картинку и блок с вводом данных на одном уровне, но не могу уменьшить блок `div`, может кто-то подсказать решение?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```
#information {
  position: relative;
  width: auto;
  margin-left: 70%;
}

#picture {
  margin-left: 10%;
  margin-top: 0;
}
```

Comment: Используйте флексы

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Для этого можно воспользоваться [Flex](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/CSS/flex):

```css
body {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}

#information h1 {
  margin-top: 0;
}

#information p {
  margin-bottom: 0;
}

#picture {
  width: 140px;
  height: 200px;
  border: 1px solid red;
  margin-left: 30px; 
}
```

```html
<div id="information">
  <h1>Information:</h1>
  <p>line 1</p>
  <p>line 2</p>
  <p>line 3</p>
</div>
<div id="picture"></div>
```